# Add value from other value with diffrent date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have some problem in mysql, I have data like this

| id | date | renewaltime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| 111 | 2020-01-02 | 1 |
| 111 | 2020-01-03 | 1 |
| 111 | 2020-01-04 | 1 |
| 111 | 2020-01-05 | 1 |

but I wanna output be like this in mysql

| id | date | renewaltime | renewal_by_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 111 | 2020-01-02 | 1 | 2 |
| 111 | 2020-01-03 | 1 | 3 |
| 111 | 2020-01-04 | 1 | 4 |
| 111 | 2020-01-05 | 1 | 5 |

adding the value with value before in diffrent datetime

```
SELECT
  h.id as ID,
  i.date as DATE,
  count(it.relid) as RENEWALTIME
FROM tblhosting h
INNER JOIN tblinvoiceitems it on h.id=it.relid
INNER JOIN tblinvoices i on it.invoiceid=i.id
WHERE h.id =305864
and i.status = 'Paid'
AND it.type = 'Hosting'
AND h.regdate <> it.duedate
GROUP BY i.date
```

please if you have same problem and share withme
thanks

Comment: Use the `RANK()` window function if you're using MySQL 8.x

Comment: @Barmar `adding the value with value before` ... this implies `SUM` to me, though in this particular case, either `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` might coincidentally produce the same expected output.

Comment: Can you show sample input?

Comment: Note that, by convention, a column called id is normally a surrogate primary key

Answer (score 1):

On MySQL 8+, this is a cinch with analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT h.id, i.date,
    SUM(COUNT(it.relid)) OVER (ORDER BY i.date) RENEWALTIME
FROM tblhosting h
INNER JOIN tblinvoiceitems it ON h.id = it.relid
INNER JOIN tblinvoices i ON it.invoiceid = i.id
WHERE
    h.id = 305864 AND
    i.status = 'Paid' AND
    it.type = 'Hosting' AND
    h.regdate <> it.duedate
GROUP BY
    i.date
ORDER BY
    i.date;
```

Comment: ID is duplicated - so I think that this is a group marker. Maybe `PARTITION BY id` is useful...

Comment: I thought `renewaltime` is the name of the output column, not an input.

Comment: @Barmar You were right, I had it wrong, as I did not see the OP's actual query.  Answer updated.

Comment: why i my mysql cannot use over (order by date) ?

Comment: You are probably using an old version of MySQL.  Consider upgrading to 8+ to use the above query.